# Conserved Quantities and Integrability in the $N$-Body Problem

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, orbital-motion, integrable-systems, integrals-of-motion

Under my understanding of integrability, a system with $2n$-dimensional phase space is integrable when there are at least $n$ constants of motion satisfying some conditions (e.g., they are in involution). I have been trying to check my counting to see why the two body problem is integrable while the three body problem is not, but I have gotten mixed up.

The two body problem has $12$-dimensional phase space, so we would like at least $6$ constants of motion. I believe, for the generic $N$-body problem, there are $10$ such constants of motion (the linear momentum of the center of mass, the original position of the center of mass, the angular momentum, and the energy), so there should be enough constants of motion (assuming that they satisfy the desired conditions of being in involution) for the two body problem to be integrable.

My logic then clearly fails me because the three body problem would then have 18-dimensional phase space and would require 9 constants of motion to be integrable. It appears that we have $10$ constants of motion so I would expect this system to be integrable, but I know it is not.

Can anyone help clear this up and show where my logic failed? I know that the three body problem is non-integrable but, just from my (naive) counting, I would expect it to be integrable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For a Hamiltonian $N$-body system with a phase space of dimension $2n=6N$ to be [Liouville/complete integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system#Hamiltonian_systems_and_Liouville_integrability), there should exist $n$ constants of motion that are (i) *independent* and (ii) *Poisson-commute,* among other things. The 10 constants of motion mentioned on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_problem) do not satisfy property (ii).